# No valid Headers on plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a plugin, for some reason when I try to upload and activate it via a zip.  I get the message 'no valid headers'.  If I just drop the folder via ftp it seems ok.  Any suggestions?

here is the plugin main files:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Album Gallery
 * Plugin URI: http://vinteractive.co.uk
 * Description: An Album based Slider Gallery.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Vincent Stephens
 * Author URI: http://vinteractive.co.uk
 * License: Do Not Redistribute
 */

define('ALBUM_GALLERY_URL', plugins_url() . '/album-gallery/');
define('ALBUM_GALLERY_ABSPATH', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/album-gallery/');

define( 'ACF_LITE' , true );
include(ALBUM_GALLERY_ABSPATH . 'custom-fields/acf.php');
include(ALBUM_GALLERY_ABSPATH . 'custom-fields/album-fields.php');
include(ALBUM_GALLERY_ABSPATH . 'custom-post-types/albums-gallery-post-type.php');
include(ALBUM_GALLERY_ABSPATH . 'shortcodes/shortcodes.php');


// Enque Scripts and styles
function album_gallery_scripts() {
wp_register_script('jquery-for-nivo', plugins_url('/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-for-nivo');
wp_register_script('nivo-slider', plugins_url('/nivo/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('nivo-slider');
wp_register_script('album-gallery-script', plugins_url('/js/album-gallery.jquery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('album-gallery-script');

wp_register_style('album-gallery', plugins_url('/css/album-gallery.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('album-gallery');
wp_register_style('nivo-slider', plugins_url('/nivo/nivo-slider.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('nivo-slider');
wp_register_style('style', plugins_url('/nivo/style.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('style');

// Nivo Theme
wp_register_style('theme-default', plugins_url('/nivo/themes/default/default.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style('theme-default');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'album_gallery_scripts' );  


?>
```

Short Codes file:

```
<?php 
    function album_gallery_shortcode() {
?>
        <span class="info_btn"></span>

        <?php 
        // Loop for Album Gallery Post Type
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'albums_gallery',
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            $album_name = get_the_ID();
            $album_description = get_field('album_description');

        ?>

        <div class="album album_<?php echo $album_name ?>">

        <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 0; $i++) { ?>
            <div class="description album_<?php echo $album_name ?>">
                <?php echo $album_description; ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div class="slider" class="nivoSlider">

                    <?php

                    $images = Array();
                    for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
                        $image = get_field("image_{$i}");
                        if(!$image || !$image['url']) {
                            break;
                        }
                        $caption = get_field("image_{$i}_caption");
                        ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $caption; ?>" />

                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Album -->

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <!-- // Loop for Album Gallery Post Type -->

        <div class="thumbnails">
        <?php 

            $args = array(
                'taxonomy_albums'   => '',
                'post_type'         => 'albums_gallery',
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            // album name becomes post id
            $album_name = get_the_id();
            $album_thumb = get_field('thumbnail');
            $album_caption = get_field('album_caption');

            if( !empty($album_thumb) ): ?>

                <div class="thumbs" style="width: 130px; float: left; margin: 5px;">
                    <img class="thumb thumb_album_<?php echo $album_name; ?>" src="<?php echo $album_thumb['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $album_thumb['alt']; ?>" width="130" />
                    <p class="title"><?php the_title();  ?></p>
                    <p class="caption"><?php echo $album_caption ?></p>
                </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- end thumbnails -->


<?php

    }
    add_shortcode( 'album-gallery', 'album_gallery_shortcode' );
?>
```

Comment: Disregard the previous comment... How are you creating the ZIP? It gotta be only `/plugin-folder/all-files.*`.

Comment: The file structure is:

album-gallery
-css
-custom-fields
-custom-post-types
-images
-js
-nivo
-shortcodes

I am creating the zipp in finder with context menu 'compress'

Comment: Open the zip in a dedicated app and confirm the structure. Or if you want to post a zip, I can check it out.

Comment: @brasofilo - Here is the link. http://l.bitcasa.com/eau_OfHl . I create the zip in osx finder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it has something to do with the Advanced Custom Posts plugin that you include with your plugin. I had a similar issue and I solved it by moving the acf folder one level down. Meaning, instead of `myplugin/advanced-custom-fields` I put it in `myplugin/inc/advanced-custom-fields`

and it worked.

Of course, don't forget to change the path on your plugin's main file to

```
include(ALBUM_GALLERY_ABSPATH . 'inc/custom-fields/acf.php');
```

BTW, I prefer to call the plugin like that:

```
if( !class_exists('Acf') )
{
    define( 'ACF_LITE' , true ); // Hide it from admin
    include_once('inc/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );
}
```

Because you don't want your users to load it again if they already have it installed.

Comment: Yep, thats how I got out of it way back when... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when including ACF in a plugin and it took me forever to figure it out, especially since I drop a plugin header template in the same way each time I create a new plugin.

The problem stemmed from the included acf.php plugin header. Remove the wordpress comment header from that file, and it seems to install fine, no matter what directory level you include it from.